# How to use nested query to fetch the data

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to suggest quizzes to a user based upon his interest in any subject. Only those quizzes will be displayed who thw User have not played and are of the subject he is interested in.

I am getting all the list of quizzes and the person with played relationship, but the problem is that I am getting those quizzes also that I already have taken...
I don't the quizzes that I already have played as in my suggestion

```
match (n:User {username :'rahulkumar6611@gmail.com' })-[r:INTRESTED_IN]->(s:Subject)
with collect(s) as inlist
UNWIND inlist as list
match (q:Quiz)-[p:ABOUT]-(k:Subject)
where k.subject in list.subject
match (uk:User)-[pl:PLAYED]-(mk:Quiz)
where mk.quizCode = q.quizCode
return uk, mk
```

Expecting:

```
HashMap<Quiz,ArrayList<User>>
```

Something like the above data structure.
But It should not have the quizzes that I already have played

I tried:

```
match (n:User {username :'rahulkumar6611@gmail.com' })-[r:INTRESTED_IN] ->(s:Subject) with collect(s) as inlist UNWIND inlist as list match (q:Quiz)-[p:ABOUT]-(k:Subject) where k.subject in list.subject match (uk:User)-[pl:PLAYED]-(mk:Quiz) where mk.quizCode = q.quizCode as quizCodelist UNWIND qLIST as listQ WHERE NOT exists((me)-[:PLAYED]-(quiz)) AND me.username = 'rahulkumar6611@gmail.com' return uk, mk
```

I am not able to use where not clause properly to filter it out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will return the quizes that the specified `User` may be interested in but never "played":

```
MATCH (u:User {username :'rahulkumar6611@gmail.com' })-[:PLAYED]->(pq:Quiz)
WITH u, COLLECT(pq) AS playedQuizes
MATCH (u)-[:INTERESTED_IN]->(:Subject)<-[:ABOUT]-(q:Quiz)
WHERE NOT q IN playedQuizes
RETURN u, q
```